# Caesar Cipher (different to others)

Tags: python, encryption

Hey guys so I 'm trying to make a cipher following these sets of instructions:

1. Print a header.
2. Prompt the user to enter the name of the file with the encrypted message, the decode 
   key (the shift number), and the name of the file to store the decrypted message.
3. Read the encrypted message from the file.
4. Use the decode key to shift each character in the encrypted message by the 
   appropriate number to generate the new string corresponding to the decrypted message.
5. Save the decrypted message in the second file.
6. Print the encypted and decrypted messages on the screen.
   I'm not allowed to use the ord() or chr() functions.

What really confuses me is the encrypted and decrypted files part. I don't really know how to code for this.

I'm pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @PrincessOftheUniverse I've seen your responses on the comment threads of several questions. First off let me say that I appreciate your passion in creating a better SO community. To follow that up though I would say that from a practical standpoint any accusations that the OP will blindly copy the answer is an assumption that is baseless without more information. I might be sentimental... I can remember being a junior engineer and relying heavily on example code to come up with my own solutions and like to assume the best intentions of others. That is the main reason I posted a full example.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: It sounds like you're probably doing this as a school assignment. I *highly* recommend that you use the code below *only as an example and not as a full solution*. I would hate for there to be plagiarism issues surrounding your assignment and I'm sure your professor/teacher is knowledgeable at Googling for prior work. Good luck on your assignment!**

I wrote a quick example of how I might try and tackle your problem. The example has a few known issues:

1. It doesn't deal with capital letters. (Other than to convert them to their lowercase counterparts.)
2. It doesn't deal with punctuation or non alphanumeric characters. (Numbers, spaces or line endings.)
3. There is no error checking.
4. If you try to convert a number < -25 it will throw up on you.

Probably the biggest problem that needed to be solved was the limitation of not using `ord()` and `chr()`. I bypassed that limitation by creating my own conversion list of letters to numbers and vice versa. A tricky corner case to make sure you deal with is what happens if the shift moves a letter outside of the conversion range [0,25].

As a side note if you want to decrypt a file you can simply open it up as the plaintext and use a negative offset whose absolute value is equal to the encrypting offset. Or in plain English, if you use the parameters:

```
infile = clear.txt, offset = 1, outfile = encrypted.txt
```

To decrypt you can use:

```
infile = encrypted.txt, offset = -1, outfile = decrypted.txt
```

**caesarcipher.py**

```
import itertools

letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q',
           'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
numbers = range(26) # Numbers 0 - 25
lettersToNumbers = dict(zip(letters, numbers))
numbersToLetters = dict(zip(numbers, letters))

def printHeader():
    """ Print the program informational header """
    print """=======================================
Welcome to CaesarCipher - The unbreakable
Roman cipher.
======================================="""

def convertToNumber(letter):
    """ Convert a letter to a number using our predefined conversion table
        @param letter: The letter to convert to an integer value
        @type letter: str
        @rtype: int
    """
    return lettersToNumbers[letter]

def convertToLetter(number):
    """ Convert a number to a letter using our predefined conversion table
        @param number: The number to convert to a letter
        @type number: int
        @rtype: str
    """
    # If we shift outside of our range make sure to wrap
    if number > 25:
        return numbersToLetters[number%25]
    elif number < 0:
        return numbersToLetters[number+25]
    else:
        return numbersToLetters[number]

def shiftUp(letter, shift):
    """ Shift letter up a given number of positions
        @param letter: The letter we're shifting
        @param shift: The number of positions to shift up
        @type letter: str
        @type shift: int

        @note: For simplicity we encode both capital and lowercase letters
               to the same values
    """
    number = convertToNumber(letter.lower())
    number += shift
    return convertToLetter(number)

def prompt():
    """ Prompt for user input
        @rtype: tuple of str, int, str
    """
    infile = raw_input("File to encrypt: ")
    offset = int(raw_input("Encoding number: "))
    outfile = raw_input("Encrypted file destination: ")
    return (infile, offset, outfile)

def encrypt(infile, offset, outfile):
    """ Encrypt the file using the given offset """
    print "=== Plaintext input ==="
    printFile(infile)
    with open(infile) as red_file:
        with open(outfile, 'w') as black_file:
            for line in red_file:
                for letter in line:
                    # Only convert alphabetic characters
                    if letter.isalpha():
                        black_file.write(shiftUp(letter, offset))
                    else:
                        black_file.write(letter)
    print "=== Ciphertext output ==="
    printFile(outfile)

def printFile(path):
    """ Print the data in the given file """
    with open(path) as print_file:
        for line in print_file:
            print line

printHeader()
encrypt(*prompt()) # `*` unpacks the tuple returned by `prompt()` into 
                   # three separate arguments.
```

**test.txt**

```
abcdef
ABCDEF
This is some text I want to try and encrypt.
```

**Example run:**

```
mike@test:~$ python caesarcipher.py 
=======================================
Welcome to CaesarCipher - The unbreakable
Roman cipher.
=======================================
File to encrypt: test.txt
Encoding number: 1
Encrypted file destination: test.out 
=== Plaintext input ===
abcdef

ABCDEF

This is some text I want to try and encrypt.

=== Ciphertext output ===
bcdefg

bcdefg

uijt jt tpnf ufyu j xbou up usz boe fodszqu.
```

Comment: Hey Mike, this is a great answer! I'd just offer a quick comment, perhaps giving a full solution to a question like this, which shows very little research or actual effort might be counter productive. I'd hate for others to look at this and thing that they too should just copy paste tasks here and get back solutions. But again nice piece of code

Comment: @jozefg - I was just going to add an additional comment for the OP which is that they should use this as an example (and not a solution) as I'm sure his/her professor probably knows how to search Google for duplication. :)

Comment: Professors (or the TAs grading for their class) usually have much better things to do than play plagiarism police. I should know, I am one (of the TAs).

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the file bits is your biggest problem, I assume function like:

```
def decaesar(message, shift):
   pass
```

that does the decyphering for you on a string basis - that is, it takes the encrypted message as a string and gives you back the decrypted message as a string. If you haven't written that already, do that first, and test it with hard-coded strings. Ignore the "encrypted and decrypted *files*" bit at this stage - programming is all about solving one problem at a time.

Once you have that function and you're happy that it works, extending your program to deal with files instead of strings is as simple as asking:

- Can I get a string with the contents of a file, given the file's name? , and conversely,
- Can I write a string into a file with a given name?

If you can answer both of those with 'yes', then you can extend your program in this way without changing your `decaesar` function - your logic looks like this:

```
# Print header
encrypted_filename, decrypted_filename, shift = # get from user input
encrypted_message = # get the contents of encrypted_filename as a string
decrypted_message = decaesar(encrypted_message, shift)
# write decrypted_message to decrypted_filename
# print encrypted_message and decrypted_message
```

Usefully, Python's file IO works on exactly this principle of converting between strings and files. If you have a file open for reading:

```
in_file = open(filename)
```

, then the return value of:

```
in_file.read()
```

is exactly the string to answer the first point. Likewise, if you have a file open for writing:

out_file = open(filename, 'w')
. then:

out_file.write(my_string)

will put `my_string` into that file.

So that means that if you do already have your `decaeser` function, then you can slip this code into the pseudocode above at the appropriate places, and you will have a mostly working solution.